# Cannot change file/folder permission on Linux running on VMware

Tags: linux, permissions, vmware, chmod

I am using Linux on a VMware on Windows and added a second HDD device today. However, each file or any dictionary that is created on the new device gets `executable` permissions which are not removable (even using root rights). While using `ls`, the folders are highlighted in green which I don´t want to have. I guess this is more related to the VM rather than Linux. Changing the file permission (removing the executable permission) as `sudo chmod -x myFile` will not give any change. Does anybody know, why each added file ends up with the executable flag and how one could remove it? Any answer is highly appreaciated. Thank you in advance, Tobi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to use NTFS (or FAT) file system on linux and struggle with file permission.

By default those fs do not support unix-style permission, but you can defined a default one in mount options

```
sudo mount -t ntfs -o rw,auto,user,fmask=0133,dmask=0022 /dev/drive /mnt/point
```

This will assign 644 to all the files and 755 to all the directories on mounted drive.

Even though, there is a way to enable unix permission on NTFS drive by adding `permissions` to mount options. However you need to define user mapping in order to use it. See `man ntfs-3g` for more details.

FAT doesn't support this in any way though.

Comment: Yes it is a  NTFS file system as I am not allowed to use any other file system (it is pre-defined by the company I am working for). I will try your suggestions and get back. Thank you in advance @rush

Comment: NTFS dose support execute-bit. However MS-Windows always sets this bit on every file (for backwards comparability with CP/M).

Comment: The problem while loading the device like that is, that I get an run-time error while running my application. `Feiled to load .../.../*.so`. Any suggestions.